# Does PowerShell cmdlet Get-WindowsFeature only work on Windows Server?

Tags: windows, powershell

New to Powershell here.
I'm running a system with Windows-10.

Is the PowerShell command Get-WindowsFeature only available on Windows Server?

**When I run this command:**

```
Get-WindowsFeature
```

**I get the following error:**

> Get-WindowsFeature : The term 'Get-WindowsFeature' is not recognized
> as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
> the  path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> - Get-WindowsFeature
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-WindowsFeature:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```

**Here is my current PowerShell version information:**

> Name                           Value
>
> ----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                   PSVersion                      5.1.19041.2364
> PSEdition                      Desktop
> PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
> BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.2364
> CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
> WSManStackVersion              3.0
> PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
> SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Thanks

Comment: Which edition of Windows 10 are you running? Home? Student? Professional? Enterprise? ?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - Windows 10 Pro. I know that Get-WindowCapability runs from Powershell/PowerShell ISE

Comment: OK, a bit of research says that on Windows 10, you need to use `Get-WindowsCapability`; `Get-WindowsFeature` seems only to be for Server editions after Server 2019. It's in the module ServerManager now.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - Thanks Jeff. That's kinda what I thought, but I swore that Get-WindowsFeature used to work at some point...

Comment: It may have, but then MS changed their mind. Assuming that they have one... _/snark_